# react native: How can I add background image to each day in calendar?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm now developing a calendar app with react-native and Javascript for the first time.

I want to add background image selected from user's gallery to each day in calendar, like Instagram's Archived Stories. Are there any references or do I have to make the calendar from the beginning without react-native calendar library?

Thank you.